# Detremine total core hours to be billed for a slurm job?

Tags: slurm, billing

I have a basic question about HPC billing. I’ve surfed the site but could not find a clear answer.
For a given job ID, I have seemingly three jobs running as shown in the attached photo. I run a bash script with one srun command using sbatch command.  I believe the 2nd line is for the bash script and the 3rd is for the srun command. I want to know the total CPU hours I'll be billed for this job? Would it be the time for

1. 3591397+3591397.bat+3591397.0 ~ 5 hrs
2. 3591397.bat+3591397.0  ~ 3:13 hrs

[results for the sacct for a particular job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaRaZ.png)

I know there are other considerations like memory, GPUs used that can change the total billing by having a billing weight different than 1. However, I don’t want to consider them for now.

Thanks.

Comment: You will be billed by <number of resources allocated>*<real time of the allocation>

Comment: @Poshi thanks for the comment. I understand this. The question is how much resources are allocated actually? In the picture "results for the acct for a particular job", are the resources allocated separately for each of the three jobs shown? The 3rd job is computationally intensive, and using the resources is understandable. But I don't understand why the 1st job consumes resources, if any.

Comment: I don't see pictures, so I don't have that information. In any case, resources are billed according to the allocation, not to the actual use of the resources. You ask for a resource set and you are granted exclusive access to those resources for the allocated time. It is up to you to use or waste those resources, they will be billed anyways.
Answering your words: "how much resources are allocated actually?" -> As many as you asked for.

Comment: @Poshi. The picture is accessible through the hyperlink 'results for the sacct for a particular job', my apologies for the confusion. I understand it now. Thanks

Comment: No, I don't access pictures linked in SO. It's a policy of the site that I follow. Any relevant information should be accessible in text format.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. This was my first post and I'll be careful in the future. Also, I already have an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one job associated to that job ID 3591397, but that job has two *steps*, one `3591397.batch` that corresponds to the submission script, and one `3591397.0` that corresponds to the first (and seemingly only) instance of `srun` in the submission script.

The first line is the summary for the job so the billing would be 13 minutes and 49 seconds multiplied by 8.

In your output, there is a one-second discrepancy between the `Elapsed` values for the `.batch` step, but that could be due to rounding errors.

If you are not interested in the information for individual steps, you can use the `-X` parameter of `sacct` to only get one line per job (the first line in your example).

Comment: Much thanks. I understand it now. I am a new user so can't upvote your response.

Comment: Accepted. I was not aware of the distinction between accepting and upvoting.